# how to modify bootstrap tooltip only for one class

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have couple of tooltips in my website. For one of them I would like to change the colour and the text sise. But for the rest it remains as default. Somehow .myClass > .tooltip-inner does not work.

Is there any idea to fix this?

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/danials/j7yp2qxk/

**Code**:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    color:red;
}

.myClass > .tooltip-inner {
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS as below:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    color:red;
} 
.myClass .tooltip-inner {
    color:white;
}
```

Here's a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j7yp2qxk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<h3 id="myclass"></h3
```

CSS:

```
#myclass .tooltip-inner {
        color:white;
}
```